# XtraReport, Change group header after detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, xtrareport

I´m hoping any XtraReport specialist could help me out a bit.

I´m doing a form, generating a report which displays a table with some dates and some info. On every page I want a group header displaying which dates that shows on that page.

For example when generating the report for dates between 2016-12-14 to 2017-02-12, I want 2016-12-14 - 2016-12-23 on first page´s header, 2016-12-24 to 2017-01-02 on second page and so on... I don´t know beforehand how many dates fits on one page. So the problem is that I have to generate the header band and the rows in detail band and then go back and change the header on the same page, which is difficult due to XtraReports hierarchical structure. Any ideas how to solve this?

My structure:

- [Report header]
- [Group header] i.e 2016-12-14 - 2016-12-23
- [Detail] i.e :
- 14   ...   ...   ...
- 15   ...   ...   ...
- 16   ...   ...   ...
- ...  ...   ...   ...
- 23   ...   ...   ...
- [Group footer]
- [Report footer]

I much appreciate all help I can get!